# How to convert an IPv6 string to unsigned char array in C

Tags: c, ipv6

I need convert an IPv6 string to unsigned char array in C, for example:
The IPv6 string "fe80:0000:0000:0000:020f:bbff:feb8:f89e", the expected result in unsigned char array is:

```
exampleIPv6Addr[16] ={0xfe, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                   0x02, 0x0f, 0xbb, 0xff, 0xfe, 0xb8, 0xf8, 0x9e};
```

Is there any lib to use and realize this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+ip+to+string+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`inet_pton()` is commonly used for converting the textual representation of IPv(4/6)-adresses to binary:

```
char *ipv6str = "fe80:0000:0000:0000:020f:bbff:feb8:f89e";
struct in6_addr ipv6data;
inet_pton(AF_INET6, ipv6str, &ipv6data);
```

Now you can access it as a char array with:

```
ipv6data.s6_addr[0-15];
```

Comment: How about the IPv6 string contains the prefix as: "fe80:0000:0000:0000:020f:bbff:feb8:f89e/64", will inet_pton() accpet this?

Comment: @RuiHuang No, you will have to cut that off first.